# unicode-math: inline math characters get stretched horizontally when changing font size

Tags: fontsize, unicode-math

I need to change font size mid document. The issue is that the characters in the inline math get stretched (get wider) compared to text mode no matter what method I tried and this looks bad (and wastes page real estate).
How can I fix this?

Here's an MWE:

```
\documentclass{scrbook}
\usepackage{unicode-math}

\begin{document}
   Same character width:\\
     123456789012345678901234567890\\
   $ 123456789012345678901234567890 $\par

   \KOMAoptions{fontsize=10}
   % or other change in size like \footnotesize \LARGE etc

   Different character width:\\
   123456789012345678901234567890\\
   $ 123456789012345678901234567890 $\par

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could force unicode-math to use the normal latin modern text font for the numbers:

```
\documentclass{scrbook}
\usepackage{unicode-math}
\setmathfont{Latin Modern Math}
\setmathfont[range={"0030-"0039}]{Latin Modern Roman}
\setmathfont[range=\int]{Latin Modern Math} %last font should be a math font

\begin{document}
   Same character width:\\
     123456789012345678901234567890\\
   $ 123456789012345678901234567890 $\par

 \KOMAoptions{fontsize=10}
   Different character width:\\
   123456789012345678901234567890\\
   $ 123456789012345678901234567890  x^3$\par

\end{document}
```

## Edit

Actually the range command is not necessary. Simply setting the math font like egreg does in his answer solves the problem for me in a modern tex system:

```
\documentclass{scrbook}
\usepackage{unicode-math}
\setmathfont{Latin Modern Math}

\begin{document}
   Same character width:\\
     123456789012345678901234567890\\
   $ 123456789012345678901234567890 $\par

 \KOMAoptions{fontsize=10}
   Different character width:\\
   123456789012345678901234567890\\
   $ 123456789012345678901234567890  x^3$\par

\end{document}
```

## Edit 2

After looking a bit more closely (and testing other fontsizes) I found the source of the problem: unicode-math is setting up the math with different "math styles". Smaller fontsizes uses e.g. `+ssty=0;` and this leads to wider numberals (this is a feature, not a bug. Wider chars are more readable in small sizes).

So if one change the overall fontsize one has to setup the math fonts again:

```
\documentclass[fontsize=11pt]{scrbook}
\usepackage{unicode-math}
\setmathfont{Latin Modern Math}

\begin{document}
   Same character width:\\
     123456789012345678901234567890 abc\\
$    123456789012345678901234567890 abc$

\KOMAoptions{fontsize=9}
\setmathfont{Latin Modern Math}
  Different character width:\\
   123456789012345678901234567890 abc\\
$  123456789012345678901234567890 abc$

\end{document}
```

In the case of the Latin Modern Fonts where the text fonts have optical sizes there is still a difference.

Comment: Can you please tell me the range for A-Z and a-z to add them as well? (as a comment, not in MWE). TY!

Comment: Well, the edit is exactly the same as my answer.

Comment: @egreg: yes, sorry. But I added a reference to your answer now. Btw: the `fontsize=10pt` is not the problem, you get a similar effect with e.g. `\small`. Somehow unicode-math doesn't setup the default font correctly.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Your 1st MWE seems to be the workaround. I just need to find a list with the rest of the characters.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Edit 2 is wonderful. I switched to it and it's flawless in my book. Your 1st MWE (please don't delete it) worked as well after extending the range to 007A plus some other codes. Thank you for your effort.

Answer (score 5):

You simply need to specify the math font. Why this happens may be a bug in `unicode-math` (or a consequence of how `fontsize=10` works).

```
\documentclass{scrbook}
\usepackage{unicode-math}
\setmathfont{Latin Modern Math}

\begin{document}

   Same character width:\\
     123456789012345678901234567890\\
   $ 123456789012345678901234567890 $\par

   \KOMAoptions{fontsize=10}
   % or other change in size like \footnotesize \LARGE etc

   Different character width:\\
   123456789012345678901234567890\\
   $ 123456789012345678901234567890 $\par

\end{document}
```

[image]

The small shift in the displays is due to what seems a bug in the Latin Modern Math font; if I do

```
\sbox0{78}\showbox0
\sbox0{$78$}\showbox0
```

with the normal `scrbook` setting (11pt), then I get

```
\hbox(7.40219+0.24089)x10.95
.\EU1/lmr/m/n/10.95 78
```

for the first box, while I get

```
\hbox(7.40219+0.2409)x11.09236
.\mathon
.\EU1/LatinModernMath(0)/m/n/10.95 glyph#24
.\kern0.14235
.\EU1/LatinModernMath(0)/m/n/10.95 glyph#25
.\mathoff
```

The difference in size is `11.09236 - 10.95 = 0.14236` (the difference is 1sp due to binary arithmetic, not relevant). The kern is added between 7 and *any* digit. No other kerning is inserted between digits.

Comment: I actually need to use `\setmainfont{TeX Gyre Termes}` and `\setmathfont{TeX Gyre Termes Math}` which have the same [bad] result. Ulrike Fischer's workaround seem to fit my [extra] requirements. Looked like a bug to me as well. Thank you!

Comment: @alwaysask Why not saying that in your question? If I add `\setmainfont{TeX Gyre Termes}` and `\setmathfont{TeX Gyre Termes Math}`, I have ***no*** problem with the original example. Are you sure you have an up-to-date TeX distribution?

Comment: @alwaysask: egreg is right. Loading the math font is enough. I hadn't realized this as I added it after adding the range-command. I will edit my answer.

Comment: well, something is really fishy. I updated texlive (it was 1 month old) and the original MWE gives no problem. But, my very complicatet preamble gives the same wrong output. I need to start digging again (later tonight).

Comment: @egreg I found what's wrong (not the solution). Make the fontsize in KOMAoptions something other than 10 or 7 (my book uses 9) and your MWE will go wrong again (i.e set `\KOMAoptions{fontsize=9}`.

Comment: @alwaysask You also get `Using fallback calculation to setup font sizes for basic size '9'`; this is a problem with Koma, not with `unicode-math`.

Comment: @egreg If I give up KOMA (replace with it regular book) and use \LARGE or \footnotesize instead of KOMAoptions, I get the same wrong output. So is it a unicode-math problem?

Comment: @alwaysask No, it's not a bug in `unicode-math`. It's the fact that Latin Modern Roman has optical sizes, while Latin Modern Math doesn't. So the text fonts are not linearly scaled, the math fonts are.

Comment: @egreg: No the main difference is not due to optical sizes but to the math script style used with smaller font sizes.

Comment: my eyes may be playing tricks, but in both sizes of the last example, the two lines for each size are not exactly the same width; the second line is (just a few pixels) wider.  it appears to start after the first "6", and thereafter, is not consistent between the two sizes.  the most easily noticed discrepancy is after the first "9" in the second pair.  this may be a browser artifact -- unfortunately, i can't test to paper (latin modern math not installed) -- but it seems worth noting.

Comment: @barbarabeeton Your eyes are sharp!

Comment: @egreg -- it's a curse.  but can you identify the cause?  i'm sure it's not the numerals themselves, only the spacing between them.  why the difference?  *is* there something "misguided" with latin modern math numerals?

Comment: @barbarabeeton There is a 0.14325pt kern between `7` and `8`.

Comment: @egreg -- ugh.  thanks.  i do think this is a bug, so i hope that the latin modern math guys are watching.

Comment: @barbarabeeton Yes, the digit 7 seems the culprit. I tried all digit combinations and the kern is always added after 7; also when a nondigit follows (in the same math font).